# how to make the following code faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, performance, optimization

I am developing a application with phonegap. on my pc everything runs fine but on my mobile device its just too slow.

i think the problem is on the show function, the android browser seems to needs really long to hide and show elements

what can be improved?

```
function show(id){
    $('.view').hide()
    //alert('show ' + id)
    $('#'+id+'View').show()
    scroll(0,0)
}


function getSoundHTML(id, myname, del){

    if (del != true){
        var imgsrc = 'plus.png'
        var f = function(){
            addToCostumSounds(id)
            alert('added to favorites')
        }
    }else{
        var imgsrc = 'minus.png'
        var f = function(){
            removeFromCostumSounds(id);
            $(this).fadeOut().next('div').fadeOut();
        }
    }

    var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('box').html(myname).css('border-color', '999999').click(function(){
        play(id)
    })
    var img = $('<img></img>').attr('src', imgsrc).addClass('sideimg').click(f)

    return $('<div></div>').append(img).append(div)
}

for(var category in categories){

    var f = function(category){
        $('#'+category+'Btn').click(function(){
                show(category)

                var categoryView = $('#'+category+'View')
                for(var key in categories[category]){
                    var div = getSoundHTML(key, categories[category][key])
                    categoryView.prepend(div)
                }
                var img = '<img src="menu.png" class="menuimg"/>'
                categoryView.prepend(img)
                categoryView.append(img)
        })
    }
    f(category)
}
```

the html:

```
    <div class="btn" id="noBtn">no _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thatIsBtn">that is _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thereIsBtn">there is _</div>
    <div class="btn" id="thisIsBtn">this is _</div>
    ...


<div class="view" id="noView"></div>
<div class="view" id="thatIsView"></div>
<div class="view" id="thereIsView"></div>
<div class="view" id="thisIsView"></div>
...
```

Comment: You could try running your code though JSLint (http://www.jslint.com/) for tiding it up first.

Comment: After reading through this a second time: is there any reason you're defining and using the `f` function in the same place? Seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i think i got the only way to improve the peroformance:
if someone clicks on a button (class="btn") he is redirected to a new fresh page that has the entire page in HTML and does not build it with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it may not have an effect on Desktops, your massive lack of semi-colons in the right places may have an effect on mobile devices.

The JavaScript engine has to run through and try to work out where the semi-colons need to go. See [this transcript from the ECMAScript specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9.1).

To be honest I think thats only a few milliseconds of time-saved, but its a starting point for now - and good practice for the future.

Comment: I'd think that the JS parser is much simpler in that regard: 1 statement on 1 line = no problem, 2 statements on 1 line without separating ; = bug (FF 4.01 agrees with me on that). So adding or removing semicolons in the code should make absolutely no difference for the parser itself as far as I can see (actually one symbol less to read which is.. completely unimportant).

Comment: @Voo - my answer is based on comments by Douglas Crockford in his talk on The Good Parts. Additionally I've now linked to the spec on this area.

Comment: I doubt semi-colons are the issue. Semi-colons are also [optional](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/) and I doubt that semi-colon insertion is enough to cause the hang ups the OP is describing.

Comment: Indeed - I was careful to state only that it may have an effect on mobile devices alone. Whilst optional it better not to use sloppy practices whilst starting out. UPDATE - just read your link and appreciate we're from different schools of thought on the matter. :)

Comment: @beartwizzle: Oh, I use semi-colons with the best of them, I was just pointing out that any modern interpreter should handle either case without any issues (obscure or otherwise). JSLint would drive me mad if I decided to go sans-colons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
for(var category in categories){

    var f = function(category){
        ...
        for(var key in categories[category])
        ...
    }

    f(category)
}
```

You have two BIG issues here:

1. You're defining a function within a loop. While this is sometimes needed, you should do your very best to avoid defining things within a loop unless you absolutely need to. In this case, you could probably move the `f` function out of the loop entirely without breaking your code.
2. Nested loops. You have a `for ... in` within a `for ... in` loop. This is largely due to the first problem I pointed out, but in general nested loops are a big no-no from a performance standpoint.

Comment: thanks, i moved the function definition away from the loop. but i couldnt notice any difference. and there is not loop in a loop. the second loop is defined in a function that is just called by a click

Comment: maybe i should use more static html instead of building it with javascript?

Comment: @nomoral: you are correct sir, though I still stand by my comments about nested `for ... in` loops in just about any circumstance.